# How to rewrite URL in JSP

Tags: .htaccess, jsp, url-rewriting

How to rewrite URL in JSP using .htaccess file ? I want to change my URL from

```
http://localhost:8080/myProject/city.jsp?Name=cityName
```

to

```
http://localhost:8080/myProject/cityName
```

Comment: Have you tried anything already that isn't working? Can you share the rules you already have tried before?

Comment: I have tried tuckey but it isn't working

Comment: I believe that you can't rewrite using `.htaccess` for JSP. Are you running from an Apache Tomcat server?

Comment: yes I am using Apache Tomcat 8